# crowd arrangement at Mt. Sinai

Tags: shabbat, kabbalat-hatorah, har-sinai

I was making an artistic recreation of the scene of Mt. Sinai on the 6th of Sivan, and I want it to be as accurate as possible.

When I got up to making the crowd of people, I was wondering -- were all of the people surrounding the mountain on all 4 of it's sides, or only one?

Comment: Not underneath it?

Comment: @DoubleAA lol well Rashi said that it was lifted above them, but that was only so that they should accept it, and (it says in the Kehos chumash at least and I'm pretty sure) Rashi said that it was put back down before the actual revelation, but I'm not sure if it says anywhere that they moved from facing it's east side (as Rashi said at the beginning of the passage) to all 4 sides, I don't think there's a Rashi that says so, but maybe it's mentioned in some other commentary?

Comment: It says in Pirkei D'rebbe Eliezer that it was in the air the entire time, and therefore Moshe had to be flown to the top after the first 2 dibros

Comment: @Uber_Chacham That's pretty cool, I did not know that, do you by any chance have a source that I can look up for that?

Comment: @Uber_Chacham well Rashi to Shemos 19:17 says:at the bottom of the mountain: According to its simple meaning, at the foot of the mountain. Its midrashic interpretation is, however, that the mountain was uprooted from its place and turned over them like a vat. — [from Shab. 88a]         So it seems to be only a midrashic version, but what about the simple meaning?

Comment: @Yaakov5777 it's in פרק מא - https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%9E%D7%90 take a look; it's about 3/4 of the way through. Also, make sure to have the blood sprinkled on top of the am, the men and women seperate and the bechorim (the Cohanim of that time) separate from all of them, and have these people at the foot of the mountain, before the fence, then the zekeinim on the mountain (past the fence), then the benei Ahron, then Ahron, and then, if you want to go like the Netziv, just the peak

Comment: -floating, with Moshe on it, and then a cloud hovering 10 tefachim above that (the gemara in sukka)

Comment: @Uber_Chacham hi I just read the park of perek 41 about 3/4 o the way down that discusses the 1 commandments ( I think that`s what you`re refferring to?) and it mentioed that after the first 2 commandments the peple couldnt take it, and so the 2 angels came and grabbedMoshe against his will and brought him close to the dark cloud, but it didnt say anywhere that the mountain was hovering, can you point out exactly where it says that, and/or rfer me to a commentary who mentions it explicitly?

Comment: @Uber_Chacham also the Gemara in the bginning of Sukah doesnt say anything about the coud where Msh was brought to was lifted 10 tefachim above the ground, it said that Hashem himself was above 10 tefachim, but that could very wl refer to the fire and it for sure doesnt imply there that the whole mountain was abov them the whole time, and    the mountai being above them may or may not be metaphorial to represent them being forced to accept the Torah because of a great revelation of energy from above, as it says in the maamer vatah tetzaveh